# Can we implement interface without overriding some of its method.I heard this is possible in some cases

Tags: c#

Can we implement interface without overriding some of its method.I heard this is possible in some cases.I came across this question recently while interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit the implementation from a base class, if that's what you were thinking of:

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}

class Parent
{
    public void Bar() {}
}

class Child : Parent, IFoo {}
```

If that's not it though, I don't know what you're thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement an interface in an abstract class, and leave some parts of the interface abstract to implement them in further-derived classes:

```
interface A
{
    void f();
    void g();
}

abstract class B : A
{
    public void f()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B.f()");
    }

    public abstract void g();
}

class C : B
{
    public override void g()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C.g()");
    }
}
```